# Selecting columns with linq with nested dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

How do I get all of the "columns" using linq from this dictionary.

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> _cells;
```

where I can access a row this way

```
var someRow = _cells[2];
```

and I am able to get a cell

```
string cell = _cells[2][2];
```

What I am trying to do is create table.

```
    A | B | C | ...
1 | * | * | * | ... 
2 | * | * | * | ... 
3 | * | * | * | ...
```

Where I get the values of column A.

Comment: I'm puzzled.... how are you getting a row object from some generic dictionaries that are only holding ints and strings?

Comment: A row is defined as a `Dictionary<int, string>` where the `int` is the column number.

Comment: Is it that you want the item with index = 2 as opposed to key = 2?

Comment: @Thomas - I want to get a new `Dictionary` where the 2nd `int` is a specified number

Comment: @Daniel: After reading your comments, I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you give a specific example of what input you might have and what output you want to get?

Comment: @Daniel, take a look at my solution. It will give you the jagged array you want, use to whatever end you desire.

Comment: @Anthony - i dont want a jagged array since the array could be skewed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> _cells;
int desiredColumn = 2;
var col = _cells.Values.Select(d => d[desiredColumn]);
```

That will go through the rows (inner dictionary) and simply pull out the values for the desired column.

Answer (score 1):

I take it that the "column" you're looking for is the string-typed value in the nested Dictionary?

```
IEnumerable<string> GetColumnValues(
   Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> rows, int columnIndex)
{
  return 
    from r in rows // key-value pairs of int->Dictionary<int,string>
    select r.Value[columnIndex];
}
```

Comment: From the original question, the problem is to select all of the columns (values, I assume).  Rows are only mentioned with reference to how the data structure is organized.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're asking for.  You want to transform this row-based lookup into a column-based lookup:

```
var columnLookup =
    (from row in _cells
     from col in row.Value
     let cell = new { Row = row.Key, Column = col.Key, Value = col.Value }
     group cell by cell.Column into g
     select new
     {
         Column = g.Key,
         Rows = g.ToDictionary(c => c.Row, c => c.Value)
     }).ToDictionary(c => c.Column, c => c.Rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

You realize by doing this you are losing the int keys?

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict1
    = new Dictionary<int, string>() { { 1, "Foo" }, { 2, "Blah" } };
Dictionary<int, string> dict2 
    = new Dictionary<int, string>() { { 3, "Baz" }, { 4, "Ack" } };

Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> collection 
    = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>() 
    { { 1, dict1 }, { 2, dict2 } };

string[][] query = (from dict in collection
             select dict.Value.Values.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Dic.Where(c=>c.Key==COLUMN).SelectMany(c=>c.Value).Where(f=>f.Key==FIELD)
```

maybe you can remove first where statement

Answer (score 0):

To get the column values for all rows

```
int colIndex = 0;    // or whatever column you want
var col =
        from a in cells
        from b in a.Value
        where b.Key == colIndex
        select b.Value;
```